# Is there a way to use a color by string name in Image like Image("red")?

Tags: image, swiftui

I am using

var displayImage = "myImageInAssets"

Image(displayImage)

sometimes I just want the display Image to be a color like red.  I can think of ways around this with if tests and/or backgrounds or making it a view and passing the view around but is there a way to actually use a string with Image() that is just a color? The closest I got was to create .png files of each color and loading them in the assets
library. It would make the code cleaner if I could do something like this:

displayImage = "Color.red"

Image(displayImage)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you want a color, why not just use a `Color`? Why does it need to be an `Image` specifically?

Comment: Im passing the images all around and using them in multiple places so wanted to just set it in one place and not worry about it anywhere else.  I'm still learning so this may just be that I haven't learned a better way to handle the whole thing.  I'm just trying to simplify the code and wondered if this was possible.

Comment: How about passing an enum with two cases `case image(Image)` and `case color(Color)` all around? That should encode all the information you need.

Comment: That was one thing I looked at but again I have to test everywhere I use it. I suspect I'm passing around the wrong type of thing.  I'm passing the string name of the asset in larger structs and maybe I just need to go back and figure out how to convert to passing views around.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to a solution is to find a way to convert a `Color` to an `Ìmage`. This can be done by [creating an image from drawing instructions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/init(size:label:opaque:colormode:renderer:)). For example:

```swift
private func color2Image(color: Color) -> Image {
    Image(size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)) { ctx in
        var path = Path()
        path.addRect(ctx.clipBoundingRect)
        ctx.fill(path, with: .color(color))
    }
}

var body: some View {
    color2Image(color: .red)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
}
```

The next steps are then:

- Find a way to convert a `String` to a `Color`. You will find solutions for this by searching other posts.
- Add an extension to `Image` to create an image from a `Color`, if you think it will be useful.
- Add an extension to `Image` to create an image from a `String` that first checks to see if the string represents a valid color.